# What video files can play QMediaPlayer on Android?

Tags: android, c++, qt, video, qmediaplayer

I use QT 5.3.1 with QT Creator on Windows.
I found in Examples\Qt-5.3\multimediawidgets\videographicsitem\ dir example with QMediaPlayer. But it plays on Windows only .mp4 H264 files and don't want plays .mkv H264 and .avi files.
Also this project doesn't want play .mp4 H264 video (and it's doesn't play any video) on Android 4.0.3 (API 15).

Is it possible play on Android 4.0.3 (API 15) play .mp4 H264 video files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Qt Multimedia Widgets module is not supported on Android. That's an issue in Qt for Android. You can check it [here](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt_for_Android_known_issues) that video display is only available using the VideoOutput and Video QML items.

Comment: Is this still an issue today in 2017? @Nejat

Answer (score -1):

I used QMediaPlayer but only mp4 audio works; mp4 video doesn't appear in QVideoWidget.

AndroidManifiest can be the solution.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).